# How to dynamically download and display images in Windows8 metro app 

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I get image URL at runtime from the xml file reader. This image URL is pass to the below method to download it dynamically.

```
 public void Display_Image(string MyURL)
  {
           BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
           bi.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, MyURL);
           Img_Poster.Source = bi;
  }
```

But this doesn't work. I don't get any image source. The above code works fine with static URL provided at compile time. What do I need to do more?

Comment: WinRT docs are quite inadequate right now.  But keep in mind that *anything* that can take more than 50 msec needs to be done asynchronously.  See what you get out of the ImageOpened event.  Don't forget ImageFailed.

Comment: Casn you elaborate a little further on how you are getting the file at runtime. Is this through FilePicker? When you mean static content, is this content that is part of your application?

Answer (score 4):

The method I suggested below is obsolete.  However, creating a new Bitmap image created dynamically with a Uri determined at runtime IS supported and working on the RTM build of Windows 8.  Display_Image(url) should work as you expect.

---

You can get the image stream using the CreateFromUri helper: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.streamreference.createfromuri.aspx#Y0

```
var stream = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(imageUrl))
```

You should then be able to set the source of your bitmap to the RandomAccessStream that the helper returns

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar problems with previously-working Bitmap code not working on Windows RT, an early attempt convinces me that it refuses to download anything unless it is going to be displayed on the UI (here, I needed to insert a 1ms delay before assigning sources just to get it to trigger the image download):

```
var image = .... // reference to animage on the UI
var placeholder = ... // a placeholder BitmapImage
var source = ... // uri to download

image.Source = placeholder;
var src = new BitmapImage(new Uri(source));
src.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
{
    var bi = s as BitmapImage;
    image.Source = bi;
};

image.Source = src;
// Delay required to trigger download
await Task.Delay(1);
image.Source = placeholder;
```

Here's another solution I've tried with success:

```
var image = .... // reference to animage on the UI
var source = ... // uri to download
var placeholder = ... // a placeholder BitmapImage

image.Source = placeholder;

var bytes = await new HttpClient().GetByteArrayAsync(source);
var img = new BitmapImage();
await img.SetSourceAsync(bytes.AsBuffer().AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream());
image.Source = img;
```

Comment: A very short & sweet solution _(#2)_. I needed one to download images from a site secured with basic authentication. With your _HttpClient_ approach, I was able to use headers to unlock the site, and **VOILA!**. Thank you Anthony.